# "Incorrect syntax near 'RoomHireDay'." when I use 2 tables to join them together

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I want to join 2 tables together, but it warn me this "Incorrect syntax near 'RoomHireDay'." message. What should I do? Help me Pls ^^

Here this my code.

```
private void ShowData(string searchType)
{
    sql = @"SELECT RoomHireDay.RID, RoomHireMonth.RID FROM RoomHireDay LEFT JOIN RoomHireMonth ON RoomHireDay.RID = RoomHireMonth.RID";
    if (searchType == "id")
    {
        if (comboSearchRID.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        sql += "WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = " + comboSearchRID.Text;
    }// comboSearchID is a comboBox.

    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataSt = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSt, "Room");

    DataTable table = dataSt.Tables["Room"];
    DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
    label4.Text = row["RID"].ToString();
    if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        //label4.Text = row["RID"].ToString();
        label5.Text = "ว่าง";
        label4.Visible = true;
        label5.Visible = true;
        //ClearForm();
        return;
    }

    //label4.Text = row["RID"].ToString();
    label5.Text = "ไม่ว่าง";
    label4.Visible = true;
    label5.Visible = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You have to use parameters.  You currently are open to SQL injection and other errors.  Specifically, your error is because your WHERE clause is missing quotes around the search text.

Comment: Also because if the where clause is added, there is no whitespace between RoomHireMonth.RID and WHERE.

Comment: Can you give me the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Probably</strike> Definitely  you need to use a white space between your `WHERE` part. Also you need to use your search text between single quotes. Try this;

```
sql += " WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = '" + comboSearchRID.Text + "'";
```

Because wihtout white space your query looks like this;

```
..ON RoomHireDay.RID = RoomHireMonth.RIDWHERE RoomHireDay.RID...
```

which is clearly not a valid syntax.

But more important, you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Comment: Thank you. It's work. White space is very important. haha
It's the small mistake that I can't seen before.

Comment: @kawaiipeace You are quite welcome. Next time, debug your code and try your query in your database management studio first. You can see your problem more clear with that way..

Comment: @kawaiipeace Updated my answer. You also need single quotes between your search text. Try it like `sql += " WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = '" + comboSearchRID.Text + "'";`

Comment: Thank you for the new code. Can I ask something.
Is it possible to use WHERE for 2 table?
(For example, WHERE RoomHireDay.RID OR RoomHireMonth.RID = ...)

Comment: You almost have it. `WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = 1234 OR RoomHireMonth.RID = 5678` (assuming RID is a number). Your first condition will always be preceded by `WHERE`, and every one after that will have either `AND` or `OR`, with parenthesis combining conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question: You need to have quotes around the text field if it is a text field. If it's an `integer` then it's fine.

```
sql += " WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = " + comboSearchRID.Text;
```

Should instead be

```
sql += " WHERE RoomHireDay.RID = '" + comboSearchRID.Text + "'";
```

Additionally as another user pointed out, there is no space between the `WHERE`.

Other points:

1. Use an object relational mapping (ORM) for data access. Specifically `Entity Framework`. Directly writing SQL isn't generally recommended nowadays unless you have specific reasons (high performance requirements etc).
2. Always use parameters when you are dealing with SQL directly to avoid security issues such as injection.

Comment: Its highly unlikely that RID is a text/varchar and it is also not mentioned in the question. The real issue is the missing space between select and `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I try for this but it's nothing happened. (It's warn me same message again).
Thank you for answer. ^^